# access div in iframe parent

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have a page which contains an iframe to another page, what I am looking for is to click something inside the iframe, which can then access or more specifically hide a div in the parent. I know some JQuery but for some reason just sit there blankly at the code editor when I try to write it on my own

Comment: Are the page and the iframe hosted on the same subdomain?

Comment: yes they are, I have access to both pages if the code needs to go in either

Comment: @Andrew Morris The code acces is not the problem – but browsers do not allow JavaScript actions across different domains. And those domains must match exactly (even the protocol must be the same – you can't handle https site via JS from an http site)

Comment: @feeela, I read about the same domain policy and I knew the pages wouldn't be restricted by this, I just forgot to mention it in the question. Thanks anyway though

Answer (score 34, accepted):

try this in iframe:

```
$('#DIVtobehidden', window.parent.document).hide();
```

Comment: will this work if the parent is on a different domain?

Comment: This answer helped me solve a similar problem I was having, adding custom enhancements to an old 3rd-party web application - but it was not the complete solution.

In my case I needed to call .trigger('someevent') on the element in the parent frame, and it just wasn't working - there appeared to be no handler for the event in the JQuery data structures. 

Instead, I had to resort to the rather hacky-looking construct:

window.parent.$("myselector").trigger("someevent")

which despite being ugly, at least has the benefit of working!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#element-In-Iframe").on('click', function() {
    $('#element-in-parent-window', window.parent.document).hide();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dSj4s/)

Comment: @CrystalMiller - It used to work three years ago, note that it's also exactly the same as the accepted answer. These days JSFiddle is running it's own iframes from a shell subdomain, so the same-origin policy kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

If both pages are on the same (sub)domain you should be able to access the parent window with:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('divId')
```

Well this is without jQuery but should work