# Load content into div of external html page with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone know how to load content into a div of external HTML page with jQuery?

Using `$('#divname').html("content")` only seems to be able to access `div` elements of the HTML page where the script is in.

Comment: What does "external" means here, another page from same domain or from any other domain?

Comment: A page from the same domain.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. And if my assumption is incorrect, please add more code to explain what you want to do

Comment: @DivZero Well, my pages are in different folders, but I guess this is till the same domain? Or do I need to set these domains explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! This is what I needed:

[access div in iframe parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717856/access-div-in-iframe-parent)

I thought I didn't matter that it was a child-parent relationship as long they were in the same domain, but apparently it does.

Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you want to change the content of a DIV of an external page like for  example an iframe?

If so, this can't be done with simple jQuery due to security reasons

Answer (score 1):

You can use `load()` to load all content , or target specific content from remote page into an element in local page. `load()` is an AJAX method. Do a little research on AJAX

```
$('#myDiv').load('remotePageUrl')
```

Or to only get part of the remote page

```
$('#myDiv').load('remotePageUrl #remotePageID')
```

API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @AspiringAqib  .. yes...both methods are shortcuts for `$.ajax()`

Comment: I want to do something like $('#myDiv').load('remotePageUrl'), but myDiv is not on the current page (where the JS is), but on another HTML page. Is this possible?

Comment: please explain in more detail. You can't put content into an element that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("test.php", function(data){
$("div").html(data);
});
```