# Hide a div in the parent of an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to hide a `<div>` in the parent of an iframe when that iframe loads. The iframe and parent are in the same domain.

Following the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717856/access-div-in-iframe-parent), I have this code in the iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).load(function(){
    $('#remove_me', window.parent.document).hide();
});
</script>
```

Upon loading the iframe, the `<div>` is not hidden, though. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors in the console? What happens when you `console.log()` `window.parent.document` and `$('#remove_me', window.parent.document)`?

Comment: Works fine for me. You must have an error.

Comment: also, check if you named the div as "remove_me"?

Comment: JasonP: there are no errors in the console, and strangely even when I console.log("Hello World") nothing appears in the console...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$(document).ready(...)` instead of `$(document).load(...)`. The `load` event is for "*any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.*"

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make sure that the parent document is loaded. Try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $(window.parent).load(function(){
    $('#remove_me', window.parent.document).hide();
  });
});
```