# Access Parent IFrame When Inside It

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to access the parent iframe while inside of it. Sort of like this.

```
<iframe id="frameWindow1" class="placeholder">
    <script>
        $("#frameWindow1").attr("class");
    </script>
</iframe>
```

Is this possible? This code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717856/access-div-in-iframe-parent

Comment: That link answers the question, but also leaves an issue out.  You *can* access across different domains, but each domain must have a cross-domain file specifically allowing that particular domain.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @Jason — (a) The question doesn't mention cross-domain support (b) That page is about Silverlight, not JavaScript

Comment: @Quentin -- as far as I'm aware, a cross-domain-policy xml file applies to javascript, flash, and most everything else, doesn't it?   I know I myself have used it for both Flash and Javascript.

Comment: @Jason — It certainly does not apply to JavaScript (you need to use `postMessage` and friends to communicate through iframes on different origins with JS). Flash has a cross domain policy XML format, Silverlight might have copied it, I don't know either well enough to say.

Comment: I can remember a good 8-10 years ago writing some javascript that was in an iframe, that could call and use javascript functions written in the parent container (or it was the other way around, the parent was calling the iframe's functions).    I haven't ever tried anything since -- has the policy changed in the last few years or so?