# How to alter css style from parent page inside an iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

i have a site that consist of a Page and an iFrame, i want to change the style of the Parent page from the iframe and vise versa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

parent.$("#ID").css("border","1px solid red");
or
window.parent.$('#ID').css("border","1px solid red");

Note: would only work if they are on the same domain.

Comment: thanks for the code works perfectly :), im also trying to trigger a button from iframe to its parent page it is possible ?

Comment: maybe you would like to check this post for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717856/access-div-in-iframe-parent

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Lyka this really helps me